# How to disable keyboard from Scrollbar in Custom Control

Tags: c#

I have an application with several forms and controls in a window. One of them is a custom control which has two member scrollbars, vertical and horizontal. Now when I press the arrow keys of the keyboard (with that custom control selected/in-focus) the scrollbars get the event Scrollbar.Scroll. But I need to handle the arrow keys for other purposes, only mouse to scroll.

The OnKeyDown of the custom control receives the event only after any of the two scrollbars are focused which is after the first key stroke. So, I don't get the first arrow press to handle, which is not good.

I also tried adding handler to Scrollbar.KeyDown event. Did not work.

How do I handle the arrows so that it does not scroll the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the PreviewKeyDown event.

It check for it BEFORE the key is pressed.

Comment: no luck, PreviewKeyDown also respond after the scrollbar gets focused, which is again after the first key !

However, I'm currently making the scrollbar focused control to work my options, not liking it.

Comment: Do you need the scrollbar to be focusable? If not, you could disable it.

Comment: I need to scroll using mouse. So could not disable. 

One correction on my earlier comment, I used the PreviewKeyDown of scrollbar that's why that needed to be focused. The PreviewKeyDown of the custom control worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could try overloading `ProcessDialogKey` in the intended component as follows:

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
{
    return true;
}
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: You sir are a genius ... just what I was searching for